# p-value calculation method

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

## Background

Trying to understand the way to calculate the **p-value**. Please exclude **hypothesis testing** here because in my understanding, **hypothesis testing** as one **p-value** use case is a different topic from calculating **p-value** itself. I believe mixing them making things complicated unnecessarily.

Suppose there is a Hard Disk Drive (HDD) type `0` called $H_0$. The MTTF (Mean Time to Failure) data has been collected and its mean $\mu=2.97$ and $\sigma=1.54$..

```
H0 = np.array([1] * 10000 + [2] * 25000 + [3] * 4000 + [4] * 3000 + [5] * 20000)
np.random.shuffle(H0)

u = np.mean(H0)
sd = np.std(H0)
print(f"mean {u:.2f} std {sd:.2f}")
---
mean 2.97 std 1.54
```

[image]

Then, run random sampling (sample size 100) from $H_0$.

1. Take 100 samples and calculate the sample mean $\overline{\mu}$ of MTTF.
2. Repeat the step 1 many many times.
3. Plot the histogram of the $\overline{\mu}$

```
def sample_means(a, N = 10000):
    means = []
    for i in range(N):
        means.append(np.mean(np.random.choice(a=a, size=100, replace=False)))
    return np.array(means)

means = sample_means(H0, 100000)
plt.hist(means, bins=50)
plt.grid()

sm = np.mean(means)
ssd = np.std(means)
print(f"sampled: mean {sm:.2f} sd {ssd:.2f}")
---
sampled: mean 2.97 sd 0.15
```

**Update**

According to CLT, the SD of the ND of sampling means $\overline {\sigma} = \sigma / \sqrt {n} = 0.1545$ where n is sample size (100).

[image]

This approximates the Normal Distribution.

```
p = scipy.stats.norm(loc=sm, scale=ssd)

x = np.linspace(mu - 3*ssd, sm + 3*ssd, 1000)
plt.plot(x, p.pdf(x))
plt.grid()

print(p.cdf(np.inf))
---
1.0
```

[image]

## Question

As far as I understood, **p-value** is to calculate the probability where the mean of the sample exceeds a certain value **m** (for right side one tailed).

$P(h \geqslant m \mid H_0)$

This probability is the area in ND where the mean is m or larger, because the ND approximates the multiple samplings from $H_0$.

Then the formula to get p-value is:
$P(h \geqslant m \mid H_0) = (1 - \mathtt{p.cdf(m)})$.

```
def p_value(m):
    return 1 - p.cdf(m)
```

Is this correct?

## Update

Found a nice example with actual calculations.

- [Hypothesis Testing in Finance: Concept and Example](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/active-trading/092214/hypothesis-testing-finance-concept-examples.asp)

When the sampling mean is $\overline {x}$, the `Z value` of the sample mean is below:

[image]

The p-value is the area in the ND where the $z > Z$.

So it looks my understanding seems correct. Although the formula is provided in the context of Hypothesis Testing, calculating p-value itself is achieved based on the data $H_0$, $\mu$ (mean of $H_0$), $\sigma $ (sd of $H_0$), and a sample mean $\overline { x }$. Apparently it stands without Hypothesis Testing.

I am still not sure why p-value calculation steps (solely how to get it) should bring in the discussion of what Hypothesis Testing is, just because p-value is used there. I only need to understand the steps to get p-value.

## Update 2

[How to calculate p-values](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQc3yx0-Q9E) gives the concrete calculation steps e.g. p-value of two heads. The calculation itself is independent from either rejecting null hypothesis etc. I still believe the calculation of p-value can be understood or discussed without talking about "null hypothesis" or "hypothesis testing".

In the video, it says **p-value of getting two heads out of two coin tosses is 0.5**. Why such a simple statement cannot be talked without discussing hypothesis testing or null hypothesis, etc etc? It is just 0.5 by adding up the probabilities.

Comment: I don't follow the basis of this claim at all:  "Please exclude hypothesis testing here because in my understanding, hypothesis testing as one p-value use case is a different topic from calculating p-value itself". This needs something better than a bare statement, since on its face it seems to be relying on a false premise. A p-value only makes sense *in the context* of a hypothesis test. There's no necessary way to order the values of a test statistic as being more or less extreme if there's no null (and at least an implicit alternative).

Comment: @Glen_b, thanks for the comment and that confuses me because I could not understand so far why "p-value" calculation steps cannot be explained without bringing "hypothesis testing". May I ask why "hypothesis testing" **must** be included to understand how to calculate p-value? The discussion on how to prove or reject a hypothesis is fundamentally required to understand the steps to calculate p-value? If so, kindly explain why. I just want to understand how to get p-value.

Comment: It's a matter of the definition of a p-value. There's a couple of potential ways to define it (but they end up being equivalent). So that we start on the same page, what's your general definition of a p-value?

Comment: Or I am happy to supply a standard one if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b, it looks there are two cases (one tailed and two tailed which will be my next agenda to understand). For right-hand-one-tailed. It looks, if we have a known distribution D, p-value is the probability to get a certain sample mean value m or large (which I understood so far but could be wrong). For instance if D is the standard normal distribution, the chance to get +2 sigma or more will be 0.05, which is the p-value for P(m>=2sigma | Standard ND). I am not sure if this is correct, hence the question.

Comment: 1. Your definitions only apply to tests involving a single mean. That's not a general definition of a p-value.  2. "if we have a known distribution D, p-value is the probability to get a certain sample mean value m or large" ... no, that's just a conditional probability. If that's all we're doing, we can just call it a conditional probability. The first sentence of the [Wikipedia article on the p-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value) is (nearly) adequate - likely good enough for the present discussion I expect - once we replace "test results" with "test statistic".

Comment: While computing the p-value doesn't require us to *perform* a test, it must still be done using the apparatus of the test, because without that, *we have no null hypothesis*, and in the absence of that, why would the conditional probability calculation yield a p-value?

Comment: You might like to note that when you refer to $H_0$ notationally you're saying "this is the null hypothesis in a hypothesis test".

Comment: 1. What leads you to want to apply the term "p-value" to your HDD example? 2. Is there something in particular you want to use this for? It may be that describing that may get a mutual understanding that could lead to a helpful answer.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b, I went through multiple YouTube, Wikipedia, Internet articles but almost no article gave concrete example and step by step calculation. Many articles uses coins but I am not still yet clear with when to use one-tailed or two tailed. hence I just invented a simple example so that I can to ask a question to test my understanding one by one. Once I understand p-value, then I would be able to have another HDD type A and start understanding how to reject a hypothesis if HDD A is better or different from type 0. There I believe null-hypothesis (HDD 0 is as good as A kicks in).

Comment: I think the best way to come to an understanding of p-values is first to understand hypothesis testing without any mention of p-values. This can be done; there's no necessity of p-values in the Neyman-Pearson framework. With a good understanding of hypothesis tests, defining and understanding p-values is pretty straightforward.

Comment: *Why* are you computing a p-value? What do you want to do or say with it?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus, it was only to understand how to calculate p-value as a learner.  It was not to draw a conclusion or decision using p-value in a practical situation.

Comment: @mon The question about *how* to compute a p-value starts by understanding *what* a p-value *is* and *does*. Your post is a bit confusing in the sense that you start throwing specific formula's at some problem or task which is stated as 'Compute a p-value', but this task is meaningless without background about the situation for which the p-value is computed.

Comment: Your description of a p-value *"p-value is the probability to get a certain sample mean value m or larger"* is false. It is a specific formula for a specific case. Then your introduction to the question becomes confusing *"Trying to understand the way to calculate the p-value"*. You want to understand the computation of a p-value, but you ignore the meaning and the function of a p-value. A p-value is not some fixed formula of the data like other statistics such as the arithmetic mean of a sample is always $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N {x_i}$. The formula of a p-value depends on the context.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus, thanks for the feedbacks. "A p-value is not some fixed formula of the data like other statistics ... The formula of a p-value depends on the context" is what I have not understood yet apparently. I will look into how p-value make a sense in what contexts. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: In short: We can not speak of *the* p-value of a sample, because there is not a single one. There are many different ways to compute some p-value. It would be like asking how the compute the statistic of some data. Then the counter question is 'what statistic?'. There are many different statistics that can be computed (mean, variance, maximum, etc.), and which one to compute depends on what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

I think we should start with a standard definition of a p-value.  They will vary from book to book, but let us choose a simple one.

*A p-value is the probability of obtaining results that are **as extreme or more extreme** than the observed results **given that the null hypothesis is correct.***

So a *p-value* is not a probability in the traditional sense.  If you would change your hypothesis, then the *p-value* changes.  It cannot exist in a manner that is separate from the null hypothesis.

You are mostly correct in that you are sampling data and finding an estimator.

For example, if you created 1,000,000 experiments of a sample size of 30 with a known variance of one, and a hypothesized population mean of zero, then you could find the distribution of the sampling means.  That is the sampling distribution of the sample means whose with 30 observations in each experiment.

[image: sampling_distribution_of_the_mean]

However, what if we had calculated the medians instead?  We would get a different set of probabilities.  Our p-value is contingent on our stated hypothesis, here $\mu=0$; our model, which here is a simple normal model; and our choice of the estimator, or equivalently our choice of a loss function.  There are very legitimate reasons to use the median instead of the mean, though it is also uncommon for normal data.

[image: sampling_distributions_compared]

But our concern is really our z-score.  After all, if we observe a sample mean of 12, its interpretation is very different if $\sigma^2=1$ and $\sigma^2=10000.$

So, the sampling distribution of our z-statistic conditions our sample mean so that it scales in a meaningful manner.  In an important sense, because we did already know the variance happens to be one, that was not necessary but that is not always the case.

[image: z_score]

Finally, if our null hypothesis is true, then the p-values should be uniformly distributed between zero and 100%.

[image: p_value]

That counter-intuitive result is true for any hypothesis test using p-values.  If you want to make a mistake no more than 1% of the time, then you want no more than 1% of the p-values to be significant in error.  Likewise, if someone else wants to make a mistake no more than 5% of the time, then they don't want more than 5% of the p-values to be significant in error.  That would go as well for people that want a 10% or 25% error rate.

The only way to make that work is for p-values to be uniformly distributed when the null is true.

Do note that the sampling method here is not vertical at the ends because it is a kernel density estimate and it misunderstands that there is no data supposed to be past zero or one.

Most simple problems already have an analytic solution.  However, if it does not, then the following steps will work.

Create the histogram implicit in your null hypothesis by repeated sampling.  It is important to know that the sample size is important.  If you change your sample size, then you should be changing your sampling distribution if we ignore a handful of degenerate cases.

If you are doing a two tailed test, then calculate region, $[\mu-A,\mu+A]$ where the probability of being in that region equals or just exceeds your cutoff probability.

Anything outside of that rejects your null.

If you are doing a left-tailed test, $\mu\le{k}$, then calculate the probability of being in the region to the left of $k$.  Do the same in the opposite direction for $\mu\ge{k}$ for the right tailed test.

```
rm(list = ls())


#library calls

library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

observations<-30
experiments<-1000000

#Generate sample of 30x1,000,000 with center zero and variance of one
x<-matrix(rnorm(observations*experiments),nrow = observations)

#generate sample mean over sample X across experiments
sample_mean<-apply(x,2,mean)
sample_median<-apply(x,2,median)
rm(x)

#create z-score
z<-(sample_mean)*sqrt(observations)

#create p-values
p_value<-2*pnorm(-abs(z))

#create plot
plotting_data_frame<data.frame(z_score=z,p_value=p_value,sample_mean=sample_mean,sample_median=sample_median)

a<-ggplot(data = plotting_data_frame,aes(sample_mean))+theme_economist()+geom_density()+labs(title = "Simulation of Sampling Density of the Mean")
print(a)

a<-ggplot(data = plotting_data_frame)+theme_economist()
a<-a+geom_density(aes(sample_mean),color="Red")
a<-a+geom_density(aes(sample_median),color="Black")
a<-a+labs(x="Estimator",y="Density",title="Comparison of Sampling Distribution of Mean and Median",subtitle = "Sampling Distribution of the Mean (red), Sampling Distribution of the Median (Black)")
print(a)

a<-ggplot(data=plotting_data_frame,aes(z_score))+theme_economist()
a<-a+geom_density()
a<-a+labs(title = "Sampling Distribution of the Z-Score")
print(a)

a<-ggplot(data = plotting_data_frame,aes(p_value))+theme_economist()
a<-a+geom_density()

print(a)
```

The basic idea is that if you covered the entire sample space that is implied by your null hypothesis, then your choice of estimator should create the sampling distribution of that estimator, including the impact of any nuisance statistics like the variance.

Let us walk through the example of a solved problem, which is testing the location of a sample mean, when the variance is unknown for a single sample of size $n$ where the data is normally distributed.

If we use the sample mean as our estimator, which is reasonable, then our test statistic is usually denoted $t_n$ and uses Student's t distribution to calculate the probability of getting an observation as extreme or more extreme than what we observed.

Our formula is $$t_n=\frac{\bar{x}-\mu_0}{\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}},$$ with $df=n-1$.  The first formula contains our estimate of the mean, $\bar{x}$, our hypothesized mean $\mu_0$, and our scaling $\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}.$  Our second equation gives us our degrees of freedom, which is used in Student's distribution.

Student's t-distribution saves you from having to create millions of samples.

Also note that p-values tell you nothing if the null hypothesis is false.  A low p-value such as $p<.001$ only says that if the null is true, then less than one in one thousand samples will be as extreme or more extreme than what you observed.

In non-technical language, if we reject the null because the p-value is so low, that is the equivalent to saying "if the null is true, then our data is pretty wonky, so our null is probably not true."

If you reject the null hypothesis, then you are really saying that you trust the quality of your data and not the correctness of the stated hypothesis.

A simple way to think about a p-value, since the area in a probability distribution must sum to one, is that it is one minus the percentage of area taken up by the null hypothesis until it just touches the sample statistic.

If it is a two sided test, then you start at the hypothesized point and work your way outward, equally in both directions, until you just touch the observed value.

For a one sided test, you start at positive or negative infinity (or a finite bound in some cases) and keep filling up the area under the curve until you touch the observed point.  That is the area of the null.  The p-value is 1 minus the area of the null.